# cloudflare zero trust tunnel wrapped vnc or ssh via browser not works

Tags: cloudflare, tunnel

I follow the article [zero-trust-mac-browser](https://blog.samrhea.com/posts/2021/zero-trust-mac-browser) and cloudflare official [docs](https://blog.cloudflare.com/browser-vnc-with-zero-trust-rules/) to config cloudflare tunnel and set browser rendering to VNC, but I get error on browser, console says `Failed when connecting: Security negotiation failed on authentication scheme (reason: Incompatible Version)`, but my remote macmini's openssl version is LibreSSL 3.3.6 (March 15th, 2022), I don't know whether it is the reason cause failed.
[image]

and I also tried ssh via browser to a ubuntu server, get another error:
[image]